# inspect outgoing packets and delay them, with jpcap

Tags: java, network-programming, pcap, jpcap, nic

I can read the content of the packets, 
but I don't know how to delay them.

*(I am not fluent in English.)*

Comment: I think you mean relay them?   similar to what fiddler does?  http://fiddler2.com/

Comment: yes like fiddler,
but how can coding that??
i want to automatize some function(catching packets, sleep(delay) them, and release them)

Answer (score 3):

Packet capture doesn't allow you to prevent a packet being sent. It is for monitoring only.  If you want to delay a packet you need a device e.g. a multi-homed PC, to sit between your system and rest of the network.  This can be used to capture on one network interface and copy packets to a second interface with what ever delay you want.

If you want to do this in software you can create a TCP proxy server and have your software connect to it.

Comment: @user3137176 A TCP proxy server just listen on one port and connects to a hostname/port of your choice when a new connection comes in.  You can have two threads, one copying out and the other copying back in.  You can also add a delay, either fixed or based on a bandwidth limitation.